Randomly select only $10$ values out of numbers $1-30$ without replacement & keeping the order they are drawn
I have values 1 through 30 and I want to randomly select only 10 of these values without replacement. Once a value is selected it is locked into that order placement from when it was chosen and cannot be selected again. I can't figure out the math behind this, but I attempted to visualize the sequence process in Excel.
For example in the screenshot of Excel, 16 was the first value to be randomly selected from 1-30. This fixed 16 to be the first value in the sequence for the remainder of the iterations. It also removed the value 16 from the selection choices and dropped the range to 1-29. This continues until 10 values are randomly selected and placed in the order in which they were drawn.
At first, I thought it would be like $C(n,r) = C(30,10) = 30,045,015$ combinations, but upon further examination, I'm not too sure that's the correct route to go with since this is a sequence-type problem.
Can you help me understand this as a theory, equation, or formula? I'm hoping to make a code that can handle this random process, but first I want to better understand what I am dealing with at the moment. Thanks in advance!

What is the difference between combinations and permutations?

If I'm not mistaken, combinations are unique ways to group values without repetition while permutations can allow repetition.

The $C(30,10)$ is not correct because it counts all the orders of selecting the same set of numbers the same.  There are $10!$ orders for the numbers you selected, so there are $C(30,10) \cdot 10!=\frac {30!}{(30-10)!}$ ways to select $10$ items from a set of $30$ considering orders to be different.  Another way to see it is that you have $30$ choices for the first, $29$ for the second, and on down to $21$ choices for the last, so there are $30 \cdot 29 \cdot \ldots 21$.  Sometimes this is represented as $P(30,10)$

Thank you! That makes sense! So the answer would be 1.0902735e+14 permutations. It would be permutations since the order does matter since we are putting them in a sequence, correct? Thanks again for your help!!!

$109027350432000$

@Lisa  yes that is correct
